# Как два раза подряд использовать strchr в языке С

Tags: c, строки, char

Нужно что бы функция `strchr` удалила дважды все символы перед запятой тоесть что бы остался фрагмент `,lok,dim` . В моем случае, остается только `,dipric,lok,dim` . Я понимаю, что функция `strchr` работает только из `const char` , но не могу понять как свое понимание реализовать в коде.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    const char str[] = "gomon,dipric,lok,dim";
    const char comma = ','; 
    char *ret;
    ret = strchr(str, comma);
    ret = strchr(ret, comma);
    printf("%s", ret);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При втором вызове `strchr` надо начинать поиск с первого символа в строке т.к. если начать поиск с нулевого, то он будет запятой и будет возвращён, так что нужно просто добавить единичку:

```
ret = strchr(str, comma);
assert(ret);
ret = strchr(ret+1, comma);
```

Также на практике стоит добавлять проверку после первого поиска или хотя бы `assert`.